# Python: Printing data from a specific href (with ID tag)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm new to Python and trying to build one of my first webscrapers. I want to go to a page, open a bunch of subpages, find a specific link on the page (with an ID), and then I want to print the link-data. Right now I get the error: 'list indices must be integers, not str', which means I'm doing someting wrong in (atleast) the last line of code.

What I'm really unsure about, is what I need to do to grab and parse the href data from a specific link - because I think, the rest is working (loading subpages). The scraper is (supposed) to grab all the urls of the Danish communes and print them, so the first line of print should be:

http://www.albertslund.dk (follow by 97 more)

Anyway, here's the code - hope anyone can tell me, what I'm doing wrong. Thanks a bunch in advance.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from mechanize import Browser

f = open("kommuneadresser.txt", "w")
br = Browser()
url = "https://bdkv2.borger.dk/foa/Sider/default.aspx?fk=22&foaid=11541520"
page = br.open(url)
html = page.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
link = soup.findAll('a')
kommunelink = link[21:116]

#we create a loop - for every single kommunelink in the list, 
#'something' will happen
for kommune in kommunelink:
    #the link-part is saved as a string
    kommuneurl = kommune['href']
    #we construct a new url from two strings
    fuldurl = "https://bdkv2.borger.dk/" + kommuneurl
    #we open the page and save it in a variable
    kommuneside = br.open(fuldurl)
    #we read the page
    html2 = kommuneside.read()
    #we handle the page in beautifulsoup
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2)
    #we find a specific link on the page
    hjemmesidelink = soup2.findAll('a', attras={'ID':"uscAncHomesite"})
    print hjemmesidelink['href']
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the wished output?

Comment: You'll probably want to fix the indenting on this.  As it is, it's hard to tell how much code is inside the `for` loop (for example).

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I'd like it go to https://bdkv2.borger.dk/foa/Sider/default.aspx?fk=22&foaid=11541520, open the 98 subpages (undermyndigheder) and print the url next to hjemmeside (http://www.albertslund.dk in the first of the 98 communes)

Answer (score 1):

first of all, BeautifulSoup.[findAll](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method%3a%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20%2a%2akwargs%29)() returns a [List](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

Also, you'd probably want to do the last findAll in soup2. I'm not sure which item you will need from hjemmesidelink so try this for your last 5 lines of code:

```
#we handle the page in beautifulsoup
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html2)
#we find a specific link on the page
hjemmesidelink = soup2.findAll('a', attras={'ID':"uscAncHomesite"})
print hjemmesidelink
```

you would print the first item this way

```
print hjemmesidelink[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! You're right, it should be soup2 instead of soup, but it only prints empty lists. The output looks like this: [] (x98)

Comment: Any idea why the list is empty? When I do it the way you suggest, it just returns a bunch of empty lists whereas I want it to return an url.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    print(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: I tried that, and it prints all of the urls, but I only need it to print the url with the ID "uscAncHomesite"

Comment: I get looooooots of output, but I only need something with a specific ID. Part of the output:
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl12$btnToggleAccessibleMode','')
#sidetop
#AccessabillityShortCutTopics
#ctl00_PlaceHolderBDKSearchArea_ctl00_SimpleSearch_keyword
#AccessabillityShortCutIndhold
#AccessabillityShortCutVaelgkommune
#AccessabillityShortCutShortCuts
#AccessabillityShortCutBund
/
None
javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl13$ctl02$LinkButton1','')
/